# Using One Key for Both flymake And flyspell

Tags: emacs, flymake, flyspell

I am using flymake with pyflakes to check my python code and flyspell to check my strings and comments. I want to have one function which will go to the next error, or will display information about the error if currently at an error. How would I write this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code provides functionality which jumps you to the next error, and if it's a flymake error, displays information for it, if it's a flyspell error, it corrects it for you.  If you don't want the auto-correction, un-comment the line that calls `'my-flyspell-message` and remove the line before that which calls `'flyspell-auto-correct-word` - and you'll just get a message about the word being misspelled.

The first line binds this to the keybinding <kbd>C-c n</kbd>.  For more information on binding keys, see the info page [Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html).

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'my-display-error-or-next-error)
(defun my-display-error-or-next-error ()
  "display information for current error, or go to next one"
  (interactive)
  (when (or (not (my-at-flymake-error))
            (not (my-at-flyspell-error)))
    ;; jump to error if not at one
    (my-goto-next-error))

  (cond ((my-at-flymake-error)
         ;; if at flymake error, display menu
         (flymake-display-err-menu-for-current-line))
        ((my-at-flyspell-error)
         ;; if at flyspell error, fix it
         (call-interactively 'flyspell-auto-correct-word)
         ;; or, uncomment the next line to just get a message
         ;; (my-flyspell-message)
         )))

(defun my-at-flyspell-error ()
  "return non-nill if at flyspell error"
  (some 'flyspell-overlay-p (overlays-at (point))))

(defun my-at-flymake-error ()
  "return non-nil if at flymake error"
  (let* ((line-no             (flymake-current-line-no))
         (line-err-info-list  (nth 0 (flymake-find-err-info flymake-err-info line-no))))
    line-err-info-list))

(defun my-goto-next-error ()
  "jump to next flyspell or flymake error"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((p (point))
         (spell-next-error-function '(lambda ()
                                 (forward-word) (forward-char)
                                 (flyspell-goto-next-error)))
         (spell-pos (save-excursion
                      (funcall spell-next-error-function)
                      (point)))
         (make-pos (save-excursion
                     (flymake-goto-next-error)
                     (point))))
    (cond ((or (and (< p make-pos) (< p spell-pos))
               (and (> p make-pos) (> p spell-pos)))
           (funcall (if (< make-pos spell-pos)
                        'flymake-goto-next-error
                      spell-next-error-function)))
          ((< p make-pos)
           (flymake-goto-next-error))

          ((< p spell-pos)
           (funcall spell-next-error-function)))))

(defun my-flyspell-message ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (thing-at-point 'word)))
    (set-text-properties 0 (length word) nil word)
    (message "Missspelled word: %s" word)))
```